# Cyclic subgroups containing the same elements of the group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

If a group is cyclic (and non-infinite), and there is a subgroup that contains more than just the identity, shouldn't the subgroup contain the same elements as the group? (I know the subgroup is also cyclic).

I.e. since a cyclic group is of the form $\{e,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n\}$, shouldn't any subgroup $H$ be of the form $\{e,x,x^2,\ldots,x^r\}$, where $r\leq n$?

(I was reading a proof where they treated the elements of the subgroup as distinct, and I don't see why that would be.)

Comment: No. $H = \{x^{jd}\}_{j=0}^{n/d-1}$ for some $d\mid n$.

Comment: I don't understand what that means, does the power not have to increase by adding 1 each time? or are you just starting at a different number?

Comment: If the power increases one at a time, then you shall get a group $H = G$, where $G$ is the original cyclic group.

Comment: Example: For the cyclic group of order $4$, represented as $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$, you have the proper subgroups $\{1\}$ and $\{1,x^2\}$. Similarly,  for the cyclic group of order $6$, represented as $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5\}$, you have $3$ proper subgroups: 
$$\{1\},\;\;\{1,x^2,x^4\},\;\;\{1,x^3\}$$.

Comment: I thought the identity subgroup {1} wasn't proper?@quasi

Comment: @Jess: From Wikipedia: A proper subgroup of a group $G$ is a subgroup $H$ which is a proper subset of $G$ (i.e., $H\ne G$). This is usually represented notationally by $H < G$, read as "$H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$". Some authors also exclude the trivial group from being proper (i.e., $\{e\} \ne H \ne G$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example: take $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, and the subgroup $\{0,2\}$. This subgroup is nontrival and yet is not the whole of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

There are *simple* abelian groups, and those are of the form $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ when $p$ is prime. The only subgroups of these are $\{0\}$ and itself. But in general, an abelian group of composite order will *never* be simple.